# jquery tablesorter not sorting negative currency correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

tablesorter won't sort 1 column correctly but another it does!

I've tried a few different custom parsers but none seem to work. See the example here

http://jsfiddle.net/jybMB/

```
format: function(s) {
            // format your data for normalization

            var value = replaceAll(',','',s.toLowerCase());

            //value = replaceAll('-','',value);

            //return parseFloat(value.replace('$', ''));

            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(value.replace(new        RegExp(/[^0-9-.]/g),""));
        },
```

You can see that Col1 doesn't get sorted correctly and but Col2 does. I suspect it's something to do with the negative symbol but strange that Col2 does work without any custom parsers.

Comment: The problem is in the `$("#servicesTable").tablesorter` function. If you only replace it with the one provided by @Brandon (and give the same id) your code works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nT5qq/). Otherwise the code in the parser is never executed (I added `alert("hello")` before the return statement and it wasn't fired.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this problem! I'll have the currency parser fixed in the next update so it will automatically detect currencies with a negative after the currency symbol.

Comment: @AB the code works outside of fiddle fine, of course the code doesn't execute if you change the ID, it should be the same ID as the table it's trying to sort. I've put an alert in the parser function before and the alert doesn't show but I know the parse is worker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this:

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jybMB/2/)**</kbd>

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'money', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
        return parseInt(s.replace(/\$/,'').replace(/\,/,''),10); 
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
});


$("#servicesTable").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[0,1]], 
    headers:
    {
        0 : { sorter: "money"  },
        1 : { sorter: "money"  }           
    }  
});
```